# Output google sheet via email

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to output my custom google sheet to a set email address

I have tried adding into a blob before sending but every time the email is sent the excel sheet that is attached is blank. Any help would be appreciated

```
 var file          = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nSheet.getName());
var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+nSheet.getId()+'/export?format=xlsx';
var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
  }
});

var fileName = (nSheet.getName()) + '.xlsx';
var blobs   = [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];

var emailAddress = "testg@gmail.com"
var subject = "PCS v5 Validated Sheet"
var emailbody = "The XLSX file is attached"


GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailbody, {attachments: blobs});
```

Comment: Hi ! **Could you please provide an example of your spreadsheet** *(with no sensitive data)* as it looks like its setup and what you do on it might be the main issue of why is this not woking? I tried to reproduce your issue but in my case it was working properly. If you provide a sample sheet I could work out how to adjust the script for your specific environment. :D

Answer (score 1):

You script works fine. I tried it for simple sheet and I'm getting nice xlsx on my email.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p8NzX0J1XhHFq6C1iSNWbs7h3OXzHKC7cDiQGYmuD_0/edit#gid=0

So, if your is blank it might be related to what data you have in sheet.

Are you using some =QUERY of =IMPORTXML function to get data which isn't diplayed?

Comment: Yes I am using some Querys e.g., connecting to Big Query to pull some dropdown values

Comment: Values might not be loaded on email send, you can try to buffer them using getDisplayValue, for example like I proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755462/need-help-spreadsheet-formula-not-refreshed-in-exported-pdf/61757896#61757896